# Terraform Jenkins integration - forcing (bypassing) the auto approval process

Tags: jenkins, integration, terraform

I am trying to integrate Terraform (to create an AWS instance) with Jenkins and need to force (bypass) the approval process. I am trying to do it as a freestyle job providing the required information under the "Build ENv" section.

I am able to create an AWS instance from Terraform. Now I am trying to automate the process using Jenkins. The job is failing because I am not able to by pass the approval process.

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TerrafromInstancecreation
[ModuleOne] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformInstallation\Terrafrom_0.12.6\terraform.exe" get -update
[ModuleOne] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformInstallation\Terrafrom_0.12.6\terraform.exe" apply -input=false "-state=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TerrafromInstancecreation\terraform-plugin\terraform-plugin.tfstate"


  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  [1mEnter a value:[0m [0m
Apply cancelled.
FATAL: java.lang.Exception: Terraform Apply failed: 1
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformBuildWrapper.executeApply(TerraformBuildWrapper.java:249)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformBuildWrapper.setUp(TerraformBuildWrapper.java:269)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:157)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1810)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

I need to force the auto approval process so that the APPLY phase can run through without prompting and then failing.

My sincere request to please provide any scripts / parameters that I need to use . I am performing this as a freestyle jenkins job.

Comment: what was the command you try to do `terrafrom auto approval` and `jenkinsfile` so far ?

Comment: Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TerrafromInstancecreation
[ModuleOne] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformInstallation\Terrafrom_0.12.6\terraform.exe" get -update
[ModuleOne] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformInstallation\Terrafrom_0.12.6\terraform.exe" apply -input=false "-state=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TerrafromInstancecreation\terraform-plugin\terraform-plugin.tfstate"
Jenkins is downloading TF and executing the above commands auto.

Comment: Is there a way that I can provide the TF apply commands and pass the req parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`-auto-approve=true` flag](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html#auto-approve) when running non interactively. This will also skip the showing of the plan before and just apply out any changes that Terraform deems necessary.

Comment: Hi - Tx for your quick response. I think the -auto-approve=true flag  is a command line flag . How do I instruct Jenkins to use this flag. Because I have only provided the "Terraform Installation" and the " Terraform File Configuration" in the build env. I has run the apply command automatically.How do I pass the auto approve flag.

Comment: [ModuleOne] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformInstallation\Terrafrom_0.12.6\terraform.exe" get -update
[ModuleOne] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformInstallation\Terrafrom_0.12.6\terraform.exe" apply -input=false "-state=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TerrafromInstancecreation\terraform-plugin\terraform-plugin.tfstate"

Comment: It looks like the plugin is abandoned since 2016 so I'd say you don't and instead you should just use a shell script that calls Terraform seeing as the plugin doesn't look like it really provides anything useful anyway.